# Why does my slider has blinking in first round?

Tags: html, css, animation, slider

My slider has "blinking" in first round of sliding and after that slides perfectly without any blinks. How to remove the blinks?

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #444;
}

.slider {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;

    margin: 100px auto;

    background-image: url(image/1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    animation: slide 12s infinite;
    transition: 600ms;

    box-shadow: 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes slide {
    20% {
        background-image: url(image/2.jpg);
    }
    40% {
        background-image: url(image/3.jpg);
    }
    60% {
        background-image: url(image/4.jpg);
    }
    80% {
        background-image: url(image/5.jpg);
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url(image/1.jpg);
    }
}
```

The first slide round has this effect, where it's not smooth, and after the first round others round exactly show I want them to be.. Any help please? Sorry if the post isn't good, I write first time here. Thank you

I tried to make the slider full screen, at the blinking remains the same, it's a white blink during the first round, a no white blinking between slide items after first round

Comment: It's blinking because the images are not loaded in the first round. In the subsequent rounds, the images are already loaded and so there's no blinking.

Comment: is there a way to solve this loading problem so that users who just came to website dont experience this blinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, the blinking is caused by the fact that the image are not loaded yet in the first round. You can try to preload the images by adding them as `<img>` tags in a hidden `div` like so

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #444;
}

.slider {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/399);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
  transition: 600ms;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0px 400px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  20% {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/400);
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/401);
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/402);
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/403);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/404);
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider"></div>

<div class="hidden">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/399">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/401">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/402">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/403">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/404">
</div>
```

Comment: Brother, I am very new to this stuff and I wasted half of my day trying to solve this problem via google on my own. Thank you so much, it helped. Now I will always know this solution to this situation! 

StackOverflow is indeed great for learning! Thank you x100